# Como formatar um número para String colocando pontos "."?

Tags: java

Estava tentando formatar um número, colocando pontos para facilitar a leitura.

Só que com o ponto não funciona, porém funciona com vírgulas.

Ex:

```
String s = String.format("%. d", 123456);

System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O **%,d** é o separador de milhar, e irá utilizar a localização padrão da JVM a menos que você especifique diferente. Para forçar a localização brasileira que utiliza ponto como separador, ao contrário do americano que utiliza virgula você pode:

```
String.format(new Locale("pt"),"%,d",1234567)
```

Comment: Só para complementar: ao desenvolver uma aplicação, é essencial pensar na localização (I10n) e internacionalização (I18n), mesmo que o sistema só seja usado em uma língua, pois o programa pode ser afetado pelas configurações do sistema operacional ou da versão do Java instalada. Então, uma boa prática, é ter a localidade (`Locale`) como uma configuração do programa e então usá-la em todas as rotinas que envolvem localidade. Em outras palavras: nunca use o `Locale` padrão num sistema em produção.